# Why does my firstCardClicked.setDisabledIcon(img) work, but my secondCardClicked.setDisabledIcon(img) not work?

Tags: java, image, swing

I am building a Java Swing Memory Game.  The idea is to click on the first card, it changes the image from a baseImage to another image. When the second card is clicked, it is supposed to do the same thing, wait for a few seconds, then reset everything back to base if they don't match or keep them flipped over if they do.

Right now, if they do not match, the second card never changes the image.  Below is the relevant code.  It should be noted that if they do match, the image shows and all is right and good in the world.

```
public void cardClickHandler(ActionEvent ae) {
    JButton card = new JButton();
    card = (JButton) ae.getSource();

    // disable the card that was clicked
    card.setEnabled(false);

    // behavior for first card clicked 
    if (clickCounter == 0) {
        firstCardClicked = card;
        img = new ImageIcon("images2/img" + firstCardClicked.getName() + ".jpg");
        firstCardClicked.setDisabledIcon(img);
        System.out.println("Button " + firstCardClicked.getName() + " clicked!");

        clickCounter++;
    }
    // behavior for second card clicked
    else {
        secondCardClicked = card;
        img = new ImageIcon("images2/img" + secondCardClicked.getName() + ".jpg");
        secondCardClicked.setDisabledIcon(img);
        System.out.println("Button " + secondCardClicked.getName() + " clicked!");

        clickCounter--;
    }

    // behavior if two cards have been clicked and they match
    if (firstCardClicked.getName().equals(secondCardClicked.getName()) && clickCounter == 0) {
        // player turn control and scoring
        if (p1Turn) {
            p1NumScore++;
            p1Score.setText(Integer.toString(p1NumScore));
            scorePanel.revalidate();
            System.out.println("Good job Mike, got a pair!");
            p1Turn = !p1Turn;
        }
        else {
            p2NumScore++;
            p2Score.setText(Integer.toString(p2NumScore));
            scorePanel.revalidate();
            System.out.println("Good job Peanut, got a pair!");
            p1Turn = !p1Turn;
        }
    }
    // behavior if two cards have been clicked and they do not match
    else if (!(firstCardClicked.getName().equals(secondCardClicked.getName())) && clickCounter == 0) {
        // keep cards flipped for a few seconds
        try {
            System.out.println("Before Sleep");         // testing
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            System.out.println("After Sleep");          // testing
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // enable the cards and reset images
        firstCardClicked.setEnabled(true);
        firstCardClicked.setIcon(baseImage);
        secondCardClicked.setEnabled(true);
        secondCardClicked.setIcon(baseImage);

        // change turns
        p1Turn = !p1Turn;
        System.out.println("Keep Playing");
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use `Thread.sleep(int)` in event processing. It blocks the GUI.

Comment: Please also provide a short runnable example ([MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).

Comment: @SergiyMedvynskyy As a beginner, I tried to stay away from `Thread.sleep(int)` because of the issues it has with Swing.  Unfortunately, I could not figure out a way to correctly implement the Swing Timer, and it worked well enough. I will try to break this down into an MVCE tomorrow.  Appreciate everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks as though there were a few problems working at the same time. `Thread.sleep()` was causing havoc in conjunction with the `.setEnabled(true)` commands.  The state of the objects were in question so I needed to clear them at the end of the code.  There are some known issues with `.setDisabledIcon()` method that many posts here say require a `.setIcon()` to preceed it.  Here is the fixed code that works with the `javax.swing.Timer` being used.

```
public void cardClickHandler(ActionEvent ae)
{
    // method variables
    JButton card = (JButton) ae.getSource();
    boolean clearState = false;


    // behavior for first card clicked 
    if (isFirstCard)
    {
        firstCardClicked = card;

        // a known issue with "setDisabledIcon()" required the "setIcon()" method
        firstCardClicked.setIcon(new ImageIcon("images2/img" + firstCardClicked.getName() + ".jpg"));
        firstCardClicked.setDisabledIcon(new ImageIcon("images2/img" + firstCardClicked.getName() + ".jpg"));

        // disable the flipped card
        firstCardClicked.setEnabled(false);

        // indicate the next card clicked is the second card
        isFirstCard = false;
    }
    // behavior for second card clicked
    else
    {
        secondCardClicked = card;

        // a known issue with "setDisabledIcon()" required the "setIcon()" method
        secondCardClicked.setIcon(new ImageIcon("images2/img" + secondCardClicked.getName() + ".jpg"));
        secondCardClicked.setDisabledIcon(new ImageIcon("images2/img" + secondCardClicked.getName() + ".jpg"));

        // disable the flipped card
        secondCardClicked.setEnabled(false);

        // indicate the next card clicked is the first card again
        isFirstCard = true;

        // indicate to the system both cards have been clicked and can clear objects
        clearState = true;
    }

    // behavior if two cards have been clicked and they match
    if (isFirstCard && firstCardClicked.getName().equals(secondCardClicked.getName()))
    {
        // player turn control and scoring
        if (p1Turn)
        {
            p1NumScore++;
            p1Score.setText(Integer.toString(p1NumScore));
            scorePanel.revalidate();
            p1Turn = !p1Turn;
        }
        else
        {
            p2NumScore++;
            p2Score.setText(Integer.toString(p2NumScore));
            scorePanel.revalidate();
            p1Turn = !p1Turn;
        }
    }
    // behavior if two cards have been clicked and they do not match
    else if (isFirstCard && !(firstCardClicked.getName().equals(secondCardClicked.getName())) )
    {
        // enable the cards and reset images
        firstCardClicked.setIcon(BASE_IMAGE);
        secondCardClicked.setIcon(BASE_IMAGE);

        // change turns
        p1Turn = !p1Turn;
    }
    if (clearState)
    {
        javax.swing.Timer timer = new javax.swing.Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

                        firstCardClicked.setEnabled(true);
                        secondCardClicked.setEnabled(true);
                        isFirstCard = true;
                        firstCardClicked = null;
                        secondCardClicked = null;

            }
        });

    // Normally the timer's actionPerformed method executes repeatedly. Tell it only to execute once.
    timer.setRepeats(false);

    // Start the timer.
    timer.start();
    }
}
```